# Would Galaxy Nexus US version (unlocked directly from Google Play) work in India

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus

Would [Galaxy Nexus US](https://play.google.com/store/devices/details?id=galaxy_nexus_hspa) version (unlocked directly from Google Play) work in India on GSM networks? As far as I understand from the [specifications](https://play.google.com/store/devices/details?id=galaxy_nexus_hspa) the voice should work just fine as it is a quad band. What about data? Seems like it does support 3G 2100 which is used in India.

[Galaxy Nexus specifications](https://play.google.com/store/devices/details?id=galaxy_nexus_hspa)

- GSM/EDGE/GPRS (850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz)
- 3G (850, 900, 1700, 1900, 2100 MHz)
- HSPA+ 21

[GSM Bands information by country](http://www.worldtimezone.com/gsm.html)

- 900     1800            3G 2100 BSNL / MTNL

Comment: as it seems to be working on the bands of your country and also unlocked then it should actually work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not get 21Mbps downloads on HSPA+, but otherwise, voice calls and data access should work just fine, provided you get a compatible SIM card from the local provider.

Answer (score 2):

I just bought a Galaxy Nexus(unlocked directly from Google Play Store) and it works fine for me.I tested 2G and 3G over Airtel Networks.